# Two panels in one JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I know there have been many topics on this subject before and I have used Google extensively to figure this out, but whatever I do I cannot get two panels to display in one JFrame. I have tried many things including CardLayout but that didn't seem to work. I have a feeling this is a very easy solution..

The purpose is to see the difference between the two panels due to the random positioning.

Here are some of the java files (only pertinent code - there is also a Snowman.java but it just provides the drawing for the snowmen similar to ghost.java):

Ghost.java

```
import java.awt.*;

public class Ghost
{
private int x, y;
private String name;
private boolean happy;
private Color color;

public Ghost (Color shade, int upperX, int upperY, String a, boolean b)
{
  color = shade;
  x = upperX;
  y = upperY;
  name = a;
  happy = b;
}   

public void draw (Graphics page)
{
  page.setColor(color);
  page.fillOval (x, y, 50, 125);
  page.fillRect (x+1, y+60, 49, 75); // body of ghost

  page.setColor(Color.black);
  page.fillOval (x+12, y+10, 8, 8);
  page.fillOval (x+32, y+10, 8, 8); // eyes

  page.setColor(Color.white);
  page.drawString(name, x+8, y-5); // name

  page.setColor(Color.black);
  if (happy == true)
     page.fillArc  (x+10, y+30, 33, 10, 180, 180);
  else
     page.fillArc  (x+10, y+30, 33, 10, 0, 180); // smile/frown
}     

public void setColor (Color shade)
{
  color = shade;
}

public void setX (int upperX)
{
  x = upperX;
}

public void setY (int upperY)
{
  y = upperY;
}
```

HalloweenPanel.java :

```
import javax.swing.*;   
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class HalloweenPanel extends JPanel
{
 private Ghost ghost1, ghost2, ghost3;
 private Snowman snowman1, snowman2;

 public HalloweenPanel()
 {
  setBackground (Color.black);

  Random rand = new Random();
  int randomX = rand.nextInt(700)+50;
  int randomY = rand.nextInt(400)+50;
  boolean randomHappy = (Math.random() < 0.5);
  boolean randomHappy2 = (Math.random() < 0.5);

  ghost1 = new Ghost (Color.white, randomX, randomY, "Scary", randomHappy2);
  ghost2 = new Ghost (Color.blue, randomX, 100, "Happy", true);
  ghost3 = new Ghost (Color.yellow, 300, randomY, "Scared", randomHappy);

  snowman1 = new Snowman (500, 50);
  snowman2 = new Snowman (750, 100);  
  }

  public void paintComponent (Graphics page)
  {
  Random rand = new Random();
  int randomX2 = rand.nextInt(900);
  int randomY2 = rand.nextInt(500);
  super.paintComponent(page);
  ghost2.setX(randomX2);
  ghost3.setY(randomY2);
  ghost1.draw(page);
  ghost2.draw(page);
  ghost3.draw(page);
  snowman1.draw(page);
  snowman2.draw(page);
 }
}
```

HalloweenDriver.java:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class HalloweenDriver
{
public static void main (String[] args)
 {
  JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Halloween - Winter is Coming..");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
  HalloweenPanel panel = new HalloweenPanel();
  HalloweenPanel panel2 = new HalloweenPanel();

  mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,0));

  mainPanel.add(panel);
  mainPanel.add(panel2);

  frame.add(mainPanel);

  frame.pack();
  frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to call super.paintComponent and instead of using setPreferredSize, you should consider overriding the getPreferredSize method instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2);
```

You are trying to add two panels to the CENTER of a BorderLayout. This can't be done.

Try:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.getContentPane().add(panel2, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

to see the difference.

If this isn't what you want then try another layout manager. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Or, if you are trying to stack the two panels on top of one another (on the Z axis) then try the `OverlayLayout`. This is not covered in the tutorial so you will need to look at the API. You will also need to make the "top" panel non-opaque() so it doesn't paint over top of the bottom panel.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I tried adding the borderlayouts and both of them now display. However, the top one has a lot less space now than then bottom panel so some of the objects do not show up properly. How can I get both of the panels to have the same size? I looked into OverlayLayout and tried making a new container for that but it sort of meshed the two together. I am very new to java and am a student to this, so please forgive me. Thanks again!

Comment: Read the tutorial on how a BorderLayout works. Your screen size is probably not big enough to display both components, so the SOUTH gets its preferred size and the CENTER gets what is left over. If you want them to be equal size then use a `GridLayout`. Again, the tutorial is your friend. `I am very new to java and am a student to this` - that is why I gave you a link to the tutorial. You need to take the time to read it to understand the basics of Swing.

Comment: I think I figured it all out. I edited the code above to reflect what I currently have. I got rid of the setPreferredsize. For the gridlayout I made one row and 0 columns to get them on the same level since when I made one column and zero rows I still had the same problem but I think it was a problem of my 15" screen size and not the code's fault. With them on one row all objects are always visible. As an aside, just re-running the program over and over shows how random isn't really random since a lot of the time the x and y positions are the same. Thanks again for all your help!